# Can I either open a Firefox tab in Chrome, or log into both Gmail and Google Apps in the same browser?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome-extensions, google-workspace

Until today, I kept my Gmail account and my work Google Apps email account open in tabs next to each other. Google made some changes over the weekend, and I can no longer be logged into both accounts in the same browser. I have gotten around this problem by opening one of the accounts in an IE tab, but I'd prefer to do so in a Firefox tab. Is there an extension that will do this? I haven't found one in the Chrome extension directory.

If I'm correct in thinking that there is no Chrome Firefox Tab extension, is there another solution to this issue that will let me keep two email tabs open?

Comment: I personally use an incognito window for two accounts.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put an incognito tab in a window with a regular tab. If I were going for an extra window, I could just use a different browser...

Comment: That's true, I admit.

Comment: Otherwise it'd be a great solution. Boo on Google's surprise changes!

Comment: Google - Surprise changes - heaven fofend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this morning that with the new Google Apps changes also came multiple login capability for domain accounts. All I had to do was [enable multiple login](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182343) for my Google Apps account, and now everything seems to be running smoothly.